# Call to a member function children() on a non-object

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I am getting this error when I try to extract information from an XML file.  The code to get the information is:

```
//retrieve amazon data
$parsed_xml = amazon_xml($isbn);
$amazonResult = array();

    //print_r($parsed_xml); die;
$current = $parsed_xml->ListMatchingProductsResponse->ListMatchingProductsResult->Products->Product;
    //if($parsed_xml) {

        $amazonResult = array(
            'Title' => $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2')->ItemAttributes->Title,
            'SalesRank' => $current->SalesRankings->SalesRank->Rank,
            'ListPrice' => $current->AttributeSets->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount,
            'ImageURL' => $current->AttributeSets->ItemAttributes->SmallImage->URL,
            'DetailURL' => $current->AttributeSets->ItemAttributes->SmallImage->URL,
```

and the XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListMatchingProductsResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01">
<ListMatchingProductsResult>
<Products xmlns="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01" xmlns:ns2="http://mws.amazonservices.com/schema/Products/2011-10-01/default.xsd">
<Product>
<AttributeSets>
<ns2:ItemAttributes xml:lang="en-US">
<ns2:Title>JavaScript: The Missing Manual</ns2:Title>
```

When i run this I get a null value, and when I check the error log I get:
Call to a member function children() on a non-object in ... on line 52.
The offending line is:

```
'Title' => $current->AttributeSets->children('ns2')->ItemAttributes->Title,
```

The only items that have the namespace of ns2 are ItemAttributes and Title.

How do I correct this so I can get the title information?
Thanks

Comment: $current is the value of the first 4 items, that way I do not have to keep writing it for the other items in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ns2` is a prefix, not the actual namespace,and `ListMatchingProductsResponse` is the root-node, no need to mention it, so:

```
var_dump(
        $parsed_xml->ListMatchingProductsResult
                ->Products
                ->Product
                ->AttributeSets
                ->children('ns2',true)
                ->ItemAttributes
                ->Title);
```

Comment: where should I add this in?  Before or after my array?

Comment: Well... take it from any point you like? I doubt you want a `var_dump`, this is just to illustrate how / where things are... First thing is to take out `->ListMatchingProductsResponse`, second is to add `,true` in `children('ns2')`...

Comment: ok, I did all that, and I am still getting the error message on the server.  Anything else I can try?  When I do print_r($parsed_xml); die; I see all the information is there, I just can't put it in my array.

Comment: It Works Here (tm), could you indicate [where your code goes wrong](http://codepad.org/Xw3EhTZ2)?

Comment: I noticed on line 18 you have:  $parsed_xml = new SImpleXMLElement($xml); and my $parsed_xml = amazon_xml($isbn); where the isbn is inputted through another file and amazon_xml is the function to return the information.  Should mine read:  $parsed_xml = new SImpleXMLElement(amazon_xml($isbn)); ?

Comment: I have no clue what's in your `amazon_xml` function.... So... well...  You definetly don't need to create another `SimpleXMLELement` if that's what `amazon_xml` returns.... But that's as far as my crystal ball can go.

Comment: posted the amazon function in codepad.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Provided the `xml` is as you provided it, I see no difference between my and your `$parsed_xml`... I suspect the error is elsewhere.

Comment: After playing around with it again today I found the error.  In my function I had: `return ($parsed_xml->asXML());` which I did not need.  Thanks again for all the help.